# How to Hide the coloumns of a wpf datagrid as loading from xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I am loading a wpf datagrid using a xml file once the form loaded.

```
private void Filter_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        DataSet dd = new DataSet();
        dd.ReadXml(@"E:/WPF12/Main27-02-15/IntelligraphicsSniffer24-2-15/Intelligraphics Sniffer/Resources/XMLFile2.xml");
        AddFilterDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        AddFilterDataGrid.ItemsSource = dd.Tables[0].DefaultView;
       // AddFilterDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

}
```

here I want to hide one coloumn(i.e filter1 coloumn) in the datagrid. How can I achieve this?
here I am giving sample of xml file

```html
<NewDataSet>
  <Filter>
    <name>one</name>
    <filter0>12</filter0>
    <filter1>15</filter1>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <name>sathish </name>
    <filter0>999</filter0>
    <filter1>robo</filter1>
  </Filter>
  </NewDataSet>
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the column like this:

```
AddFilterDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```